# Getting a contour plot to use data from a CSV file

Tags: python, contour

Hi experienced python community.
I often collect magnetic data as part of my job but I have to wait until I am back from the field to process the data to check it for quality. This data comes in this format:-

Time,F,Ef,FP,Easting,Northing,Height
21:51:02,53169.31,-14.3,-17.79,386330.362,7371876.155,540.939

This can be outputted in different formats such as txt, xls or in this case a csv. My aim is to be able to plot it quickly on a laptop and check that there is no contamination to the data.
Using Google lead me to stackoverflow and looking through various posts I have come up with the script which is below. Thank you to all for these posts.
My problems is that I can read the csv file but I can't understand how to then get that data into the plotting section and removing the unwanted numbers from line 27 onwards. I am sure you will find it rather simple but I have been going around in circles for the last 2 weeks due to my lack of experience. Thank you to all who reply.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as ml

f = open("filename.csv")
data = np.genfromtxt('filename.csv', dtype=[('Time',float),('F',float),('Ef',float),
                                   ('FP',float),('E',float),('N',float),('H',float)],
                                   comments='"', delimiter=',')

#only here so that I can see the file is being 
#read so will probably remove it later
for line in f:
    print line

#below is copied from elsewhere in stackoverflow and trying to adapt
#to my needs so at the moment I get this a Duplicate Point Warning. 
#So I need to call the above into what is below. 
ndata = 100
ny, nx = 100, 200
xmin, xmax = 1, 50
ymin, ymax = 1, 50

x = np.random.randint(xmin, xmax, ndata)
y = np.random.randint(ymin, ymax, ndata)
z = np.random.random(ndata)

xi = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, nx) #
yi = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, ny) #
zi = ml.griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi) #

plt.contour(xi, yi, zi, 15, linewidths = 0.5, colors = 'k')
plt.pcolormesh(xi, yi, zi, cmap = plt.get_cmap('rainbow'))

plt.colorbar() 
plt.scatter(x, y, marker = 'o', c = 'b', s = 5, zorder = 10)
plt.xlim(xmin, xmax)
plt.ylim(ymin, ymax)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

Two things.  First, you're doing a good deal more work than necessary when reading in the data.  As long as you always have exactly one header line, you should just do something simple like

```
data = np.genfromtxt('filename.csv', skip_header=1, delimiter=',')
```

Here, the `skip_header=1` just says to skip the first line.  Note that your data will have nan in the first column.  That's fine; it just says that numpy doesn't recognize your time string.  But I assume you don't need that for plotting.  Note that you don't need to do `f = open("filename.csv")` at all, and if you ever do want to, be sure to use `f.close()` once you're done with it.

Second, to plot, you need to reshape your data.  The `plt.contour` function takes three main arguments.  The first and second specify your x and y coordinates, while the third specifies the z values.  If there are `N_x` and `N_y` coordinate values, then z has to have `N_x` * `N_y` values.

I'll have to assume that your CSV file is in some particular order.  Here, I'll assume that it first goes through values of Easting, then repeats the values of Easting for different values of Northing.  Then your data will be something like

```
x = data[:N_x,4]
y = data[::N_x,5]
z = data[:,6].reshape(N_y,N_x)
```

Here, `data[:N_x,4]` takes the first `N_x` values from the 5th column (which is number 4 when you start with 0), which should give you all the different x values.  Then, `data[::N_x,5]` takes all the numbers from the 6th column, but skips N_x at a time, so that it gets the different y values.  Finally, the `reshape` command takes your Height data, and makes it into a rectangular array for plotting.  If you want something other than Height, use a value other than 6.

Then, you simply plot the data with something like

```
plt.contour(x,y,z)
plt.show()
```

Everything else in that lower section in your code is either to construct some random sample data, or to add other bells and whistles to the plot.  It's probably best to play around with those only after you get something basic working.

Comment: Thank you Mike I will give it a try and see how I go.

Comment: Sorry.  I was probably completely wrong about your data shape.  Will correct momentarily.

Comment: @Mike Your explanation was really great and helped me a ton! Just one thing, if you extract the unique values of x and y why don't you perform a meshgrid or does plt.contour take care of that ?